# Unable to use GAE bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to use bulkloader, but getting this error.
Droping --application argument doesn't help.
I'm using python2.7.

Command used is this :

```
kc@Jaguareins:~/lafolle$ ../google_appengine/appcfg.py  create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml . --application=mercipristo
```

Error I'm getting is this :

```
[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-0] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 176, in WorkOnItems
    status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
  File "/home/kc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 764, in PerformWork
    transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "/home/kc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1170, in _TransferItem
    self, retry_parallel=self.first)
  File "/home/kc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1471, in GetEntities
    results = self._QueryForPbs(query)
  File "/home/kc/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1442, in _QueryForPbs
    raise datastore._ToDatastoreError(e)
BadRequestError: app s~mercipristo cannot access app mercipristo's data
```

Thanks

Comment: So did you try `--application=s~mercipristo`?

Comment: No I did not. After trying your suggestion, I got : Authentication Failed.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=http://mercipristo.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --application=s~mercipristo
```

as suggested here :

https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/092f97bd2ec83bbd

Comment: Before posting problem here I posted this on Google Groups. After which I read announcement which stated that "Google App Engine community support is moving to Stack Overflow". I got this answer there.